# Finding two peaks of a plot (dataset)

Tags: plotting, maximum

I have a dataset which on plotted looks like the following:
[image]

As you can see there are two maximas around origin, I want to find out the (x,y) value of both of them, is there a way to do so?

Comment: Maybe look at FindPeaks.

Comment: @bills I tried using it, I am not sure how to use it on a dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your data goes back and forth like a hysteresis measurement, so I've created the following artificial data:

```
dat1 = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 4}, {7, 
3}, {8, 4}, {9, 5}, {10, 4}, {11, 3}, {12, 2}, {13, 1}, {14, 
0}, {13, 0.5}, {12, 1}, {11, 1.5}, {10, 2}, {9, 2.5}, {8, 3}, {7, 
2.5}, {6, 3}, {5, 2.5}, {4, 2}, {3, 1.5}, {2, 1}, {1, 0.5}, {0, 
0}};
ListLinePlot[dat1]
```

[image: Plot of artificial dataset.]

The trick to using `FindPeaks` is that it only wants a 1D list of numbers (the y-values from your data).

```
pks = FindPeaks[dat1[[All, 2]]];
ListLinePlot[
   dat1,
   Epilog -> {
      ColorData[85][1],
      AbsolutePointSize[8],
      Point@dat1[[pks[[All, 1]]]]
   }
]
dat1[[pks[[All, 1]]]]
```

[image: Plot of artificial data with peak points labelled.]

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 5 \\
 9 & 5 \\
 8 & 3 \\
 6 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

The output of `FindPeaks` is a list which has the position in the list in the first column and the intensity in the second column. This is why I use `dat1[[pks[[All, 1]]]]` - this extracts the actual points with those positions from `dat1` and tells use their actual x and y coordinates.

`FindPeaks` should work fine on your data from the look of the graph you posted. If you end up with more complex data, sometimes it becomes necessary to specify further arguments to `FindPeaks` as shown in the documentation. One thing that I sometimes find useful is when I'm happy with the shape of the peaks that it identifies but I want them to be above a particular threshold, I might use `FindPeaks[dat1[[All, 2]], Automatic, Automatic, 2]`. This will only return peaks that are above 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!

Comment: Actually, I faced a problem, my data set is {{-10000., -0.00105184}, {-9000., -0.000927284}, {-8000., \
-0.000775044}, {-7000., -0.000664323}, {-6000., -0.000525922}, \
{-5000., -0.000470562}, {-4000., -0.000346002}, {-2999.9, \
-0.000193761}, {-2000., -0.0000415202}, {-999.99, 
  0.0000968804}, {0.020719, -0.0000553603}, {1000., 
  0.000249121}, {2000., 0.000318321}, {3000., 0.000346002}, {4000., 
  0.000318321}, {5000., 
  0.000249121}, {6000., -0.0000276801}, {7000., -0.000525922}, \
{8000., -0.000595123}, {9000., -0.000941124}, {10000., -0.00113489}} and I cannot get right answer

Comment: @Indeterminate Hmmm, it seems to work for me. It tells me theres a a local maximum at `{-999.99, 0.0000968804}` and a global maximum at `{3000, 0.000346002}`. What are you getting?

Comment: When I do FindPeaks[datalist[[All, 2]]], I get this weird output {{3/2, -0.000605458}, {1, -0.000605458}, {1, -0.000605458}, {3/
  2, -0.000605458}, {3/
  2, -0.000605458}, {2, -0.00124197}, {1, -0.000605458}, {3/
  2, -0.000605458}, {2, -0.00124197}, {1, -0.000605458}, {3/
  2, -0.000605458}, {3/2, -0.000605458}, {2, -0.00124197}, {3/
  2, -0.000605458}, {2, -0.00124197}, {1, -0.000605458}, {3/
  2, -0.000605458}, {2, -0.00124197}, {2, -0.00124197}, {1, \
-0.000605458}, {2, -0.000605458}, {2, -0.00124197}, {1, -0.000605458}}

Comment: I keep getting this error :MorphologicalComponents::imginv: Expecting an image or graphics instead of {<<1>>}.

Comment: @Indeterminate There is no value -0.000605458 in the data you gave me above, so `FindPeaks` should not be able to return such a value. Are you sure that `datalist` is the set of data you posted above? It may have been overwritten by another calculation. If you try it with the data above and with a fresh kernel, it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I get this output: {{3/2, -0.00105184}, {1, -0.00105184}, {1, -0.00105184}, {3/
  2, -0.00105184}, {3/
  2, -0.00105184}, {2, -0.000927284}, {1, -0.00105184}, {3/
  2, -0.00105184}, {2, -0.000927284}, {1, -0.00105184}, {3/
  2, -0.00105184}, {3/2, -0.00105184}, {2, -0.000927284}, {3/
  2, -0.00105184}, {2, -0.000927284}, {1, -0.00105184}, {3/
  2, -0.00105184}, {2, -0.000927284}, {2, -0.000927284}, {1, \
-0.00105184}, {2, -0.00105184}, {2, -0.000927284}, {1, -0.00105184}}

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate `Head[datalist]` and `Dimensions[datalist]`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93176/discussion-between-indeterminate-and-massdefect).

Comment: I get List and {21,2}